# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Color' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter & I'm trying to build a simple **'Hello World!'** app with a gradient background but I keep getting this error:

[image]

Here are the only 3 relevant files:

main.dart:

```
import 'package:first_app/gradient_container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GradientContainer(
          Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 190, 255),
          Color.fromARGB(255, 81, 34, 163),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

gradient_container.dart:

```
import 'package:first_app/custom_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const startAlignment = Alignment.topLeft;
const endAlignment = Alignment.bottomRight;


class GradientContainer extends StatelessWidget {
 
  const GradientContainer(this.color1, this.color2, {super.key});

  final Color color1;
  final Color color2;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [color1, color2],
          begin: startAlignment,
          end: endAlignment,
        ),
      ),
      child: const Center(child: CustomText('Hello World!!')),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this file is relevant but I'll put it there just incase.
custom_text.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomText(this.text, {super.key});

  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Text(
      text,
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white, 
        fontSize: 28,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran your current code samples but wasn't able to reproduce it. Can you [edit] your question to make the reproducible using the most minimal amout of code?

Comment: I have a feeling that you forgot to `return` in `CustomText`. Can you share that widget?

Comment: @MendelG Im not sure what you mean by reducing the code but would you like to see the customText.dart file ?

Comment: @MendelG I put the custom_text.dart file there

Comment: What I mean is, that your current code doesn't reproduce the error that you're receiving. Try to reproduce the error and update the question.

Comment: @MendelG You mean you tried it & there was no error? I just copied it straight from the code editor & pasted it. I'm still getting the error so idk he to reproduce the error when I'm still getting it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256473/discussion-between-mendelg-and-yuri-mckoy).

Comment: @MendelG Ok I works now, I just had to complete shut down the app & reboot it